# Displaying object array

Tags: angularjs

Within an angular template I would like to display results if they are available within the object when using ng-repeat.

Example:

```
[  
    {
       name:"John"
       picture:"john.jpg"
    }
    {
       name:"Tony"
    }
]
```

At the moment it is displaying an error because I'm trying to get the image on every loop, how can I check if it is available before I use it within the template.

Answer (score 1):

use ng-if to show the image conditionally, e.g.:

```
ng-if="!!person.picture"
```

Comment: only `ng-if="person.picture"` is enough